# how can i track a paypal button click with a tag manager trigger?

Tags: button, paypal, triggers, click, google-tag-manager

Can you please help me with transforming a paypal buy now button click in a trigger on Google Tag Manager?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXX">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Click to buy">Click to buy</td></tr>. 
<tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="Buy 1">Buy 1</option>
<option value="Buy 2">Buy 3</option>
<option value="Buy 3">Buy 3</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Byu with paypal">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "form submission" trigger in GTM and compare the URL of the form so that it only triggers on the correct form.

More info here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679217?hl=en